# UITextField and UIButton are not clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, svprogresshud

I am implementing simple UI for URL checking. For this, I used textField and button objects.

When I run the program first time, textField and button will work fine but when I click on the done button on the keyboard then the keyboard is dismissed. Now I want to edit the textField and when I am trying to click on textField it is not clickable or not showing the keyboard. same thing happened to the button, next button is also not clickable.

Here is the code I wrote for the button action

```
- (IBAction)urlNextButtonAction:(id)sender {

    [self.urlTextfield resignFirstResponder];

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Verifying URL"];
    [self URLValidationMethod];
}
```

[Please check this video you will understand the problem very easily](https://youtu.be/1lANCbOsOMw)

This is the ViewController screenshot from storyboard

[image]

Comment: Can you show the code for the `Button`'s click event?

Comment: the first time it is working, a second time onwards either textField working nor button is working

Comment: did you add a keyboard notification if yes can you please show the method that'll triggered for notification.

Comment: no, I did not added keyboard notification

Comment: Did you used `scrollView` there?

Comment: Make sure you remove SVProgressHUD as soon a you don't need it any more. Seems the problem is here. It blocks app UI. And also make sure you do it on the Main thread

Comment: @Alexey Let me check it. And another thing is that after clicking on button SVProgressHUD is not showing in iPod touch and iPhone 5 device

Comment: what is the view between urltextfield and label

Comment: You have some view between label and button. That could be possible cause.

Comment: it is view used for showing line below textField

Answer (score 0):

There could be several issue with this..

1. Check either Textfield delegate might not be or properly set.
2. Try to debug textfield delegate methods are they working.

it would be helpful if you show what you have written in keyboardShouldReturn method.

Comment: It is working in iPhone or iPad even simulator except for iPod touch device and iPhone 5 simulator. If the issue with Textfield delegate then it is not working on other devices also.

Comment: then try to run it in iphone device instead of simulator, there you can get the exact result, simulator sometimes misbehave, I've also faced such issues with simulator.

Comment: it is working in iPhone 8 and iPad, it is not working in iPod touch device

Comment: No, run it in real iphone device not simulator one

Comment: it is working in real iPhone device but not working in iPod touch device

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is with the `SVProgressHud`. You should remove it as soon as you task is completed by calling `[SVProgressHud dismiss]` or else it will block the `UI`.

Comment: I removed SVProgressHud, but still same issue

Comment: Show the `storyboard` design of the `ViewController` please!

Comment: Is there any subviews which holds your textfield and button?

Comment: please check updated screenshot of UI from storyboard

Comment: That was exactly what was needed. Let me check once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174217/discussion-between-ipeter-and-priyanka-patil).